# Setup Qt remotely deploy with board

Tags: qt, deployment, remote-debugging

so here's the question.. 
I'm developing a embedded linux program using qt 4.7..
I was able to cross compile and run withou success, but i'm trying to run thru my pc Qt (with remotely deploy) I was able to initialize and connect with ssh and i get "test successfull" when i make it with qt option. 
I searched that i needed to include the target path in the project to solve "Cannot run: no command given"

The problem is, when i add:

```
target.files = EmbeddedSystem
target.path = /home/plg

INSTALLS += target
```

to the .pro, i get the error "error: SFTP initialization failed: The SFTP server finished unexpectedly with exit code 127."

Btw, i'm using mini6410.. Thanks!!

Comment: In your build kit config, choose the device that you added.

Comment: Also, I think you mean run with success/ran successfully?

Comment: Ok, gonna check that to see if i find anything.. Haha sorry for my english :/ far from beeing my native/fluent language

Comment: checked once again for the kit, everything sounds to be configured properly :/

Comment: One thing i found weird is that in project config/deployment, the local file path is set to the non build-executable. could that be a problem?

Comment: Just being more specific: Go to Tools>Options>Build & Run>Kits Tab. Select the appropriate build kit that you use and select the Device Type and Device. Let me know if this helps :)
If not, could you check to see what happens when you sftp to your device from terminal?

Comment: The local file path should be the executable that is built by the kit. What does it look like for you?

Comment: The kit is set ok, if i sftp i need to input the password, case the password is correct i'm automatically/instantaneously disconnected, but if i do thru ssh i'm able to keep the communication.
If i click Projects (in the left corner tab) i get as local file path "/home/gimenez/Desktop/QT/EmbeddedSystem/EmbeddedSystem", my cross-compiled executable is set in "..../QT/build-EmbeddedSystem-Qt4.../EmbeddedSystem"

Comment: If your project is named `EmbeddedSystem`, that looks good. Try @Scab's answer. I think that's a good suggestion.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error might comes from your `ssh` server/client on your embedded device.

Running the connexion test successfully doesn't mean that you can transfer files using SFTP.

If you are using `OpenSSH` then it is ok but `Dropbear` (for example) is a lightweight server/client that supports `ssh` but not SFTP.

Comment: Yes, i cross compiled OpenSSH, i followed a "tutorial" to do that, let me know if the link would help (it also came with SSL and zlib).. Is there a way to make this test to see if my SFTP is good/working?

Comment: Oh.. i dont know if when i do press the "play" button the program should be displayed in my embedded, this means, if i press play and thru command line type "ls", the program isnt there like it would if i had transfer manually thru ftp.

Comment: I suggest you check SFTP manually from the command line and then, Qt's deployment step following http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deployment-embedded-linux.html.

Comment: Ok, so i found out that i had to modify sshd_config and my cross compilation (that i ran with ./build on host) made the worng cross compile of sftp-server exec, so i did that manually and placed on the right folder of my board. Everything works great! I'm just having a little bit of problem with the run section, my program exec is successfully tranfer to my board but the run doesnt seems to find it.. But i really do appreciate the help, thank you so much!

Comment: Regarding the second problem, add a line `TARGET = <projectName>` in the .pro file. Check if the `Executable on device` field in the run step is correct. If it is wrong, you can use the `Alternate Command` field instead. If everything above is alright, make sure to add the correct run arguments (like `-qws` if you use `QWSServer`)

Comment: I tryed that "automatic" way with no success, but didnt look deep into it since i do have to execute the app thru a script, otherwise the tslib calibration will be lost. The scrip is working as i teste executing manually thru telnet. In my .pro i added: `TARGET += EmbeddedSystem` `target.path = /home/plg` `INSTALLS += target` in my build config, thats what is setup: 
`Local executable: /home/gimenez/Desktop/QT/EmbeddedSystem/EmbeddedSystem`
`Remote executeble: /home/plg/Script/startscript.sh`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell my application output in qt.. 
`Changing password for root\n
New password: \n
Retype password:\n 
Password for root changed by root`

Comment: OK, i was able to rum my app with qt play.. the thing is, i had to include the ececutable in my /etc/profile txt, it seems like the run is redirected to this script and not the one specified previously
Thanks again, guys !!